# React Native - this.setState is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile, react-navigation

### Technology used:

- React Native
- [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/)

### Problem:

`this.setState` is not a function.

### Code:

#### Router.js

```
export const Router = TabNavigator({
  ColorPicker: { screen: ColorPicker },
  Palette: { screen: Palette }
});
```

#### App.js

```
assignScreenType = screenType => {
  this.setState({
    currentScreen: screenType
  });
};

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <Router
      screenProps={
        { state, updateRed, updateGreen, updateBlue, updateCyan, updateMagenta, updateYellow, updateBlack, calculateCMYK, calculateRGB, convertToHex, assignScreenType, renderSlider, saveColorSelection }
      }
    />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

#### Colors.js

```
<Button
  title="Test 1"
  onPress={ () => console.log((this.props.screenProps.assignScreenType))}
/>

<Button
  title="Test 2"
  onPress={ () => this.props.screenProps.assignScreenType('HEXScreen') }
 />
```

#### What the console.log reveals:

[image: console.log(); message]

#### What I've tried:

- I've moved my method underneath `class App extends Component` and above `render () {}`.  This alleviates the `this.setState is not a function` but then introduces a new error: `ReferenceError: assignScreenType is not defined`.
- When the method was undereath `class App extends Component` and above `render () {}`, I tried passing `assignScreenType` in the screenProps portion of the code using the keyword `this`, like such:  `...this.assignScreenType` I get a new error of `this2.props.screenProps.assignScreenType` is not a function because the method is now undefined.
- I've moved my method under the `render() {}` and defined the method as a constant.  This gets rid of all errors but now no action actually occurs.
- I've tried using the `constructor` `super();` syntax.
- I've tried currying the method and having it above `class App extends Component` and then when calling the function in Colors.js, removing the anonymous function wrapping `() =>`
- I've reached out to the React Native community via Discord with no luck either.

#### Results

Anything I've tried so far results in one of the following errors:
- `this.setState is not a function`
- `this.props.screenProps.assignScreenType is not a function`
- No action occurs.

I've been at this for hours now and I've had no luck.  I've tried several solutions, I've tried asking another developer and I've tried asking the React Native community in Discord.  I have no issue passing props/state/ethods when using just React but trying to pass props/state/methods via React Navigation isn't working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define the method on the class so that it will have the correct `this` context, and then reference the method in your `render` method with `this.assignScreenType`:

```
class App extends Component {

  assignScreenType = screenType => {
    this.setState({
      currentScreen: screenType
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
    <Router
      screenProps={
        { assignScreenType: this.assignScreenType, /* ...your other screenProps */ }
      }
    />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your solution worked.  I originally had all my methods defined on the class.  HOWEVER, the part of your solution I never even thought of was:  When you specifically typed:  `{ assignScreenType: this.assignScreenType }` -- I only ever just passed `assignScreenType` to `screenProps`.  And anytime I tried to put `this.assignScreenType`, I'd get the error that `this` is a reserved word.  I didn't even think about using an object key/pair.  You are my hero.  Thank you so much!  -- I accepted your answer.  Have a great day man!

Comment: key/value pair*

Answer (score 0):

The following wont work as arrow functions dont have a context (aka `this`) at all:

```
 assignScreenType = screenType => {
   this.setState({
```

Therefore make it a regular function:

```
 function assignScreenType( screenType) {
   this.setState({
```

Then you do the following:

```
  this.props.screenProps.assignScreenType('HEXScreen')
```

Which wont work either as it calls the function with the context being `screenProps`, you need to change the context there:

```
  this.props.screenProps.assignScreenType.call(this, 'HEXScreen')
```

Comment: OP wants `this` to refer to the component instance so it does need to be a class method - or in this case a function property on the class.